# security constraint doesn't open pages via HTTPS

Tags: jakarta-ee, https, security-constraint

i want some of my pages to be opened securely. most of those pages are 
started with the name "my_Account_"

as example one of those page is "my_account_add_credit_card.xhtml"

in order to do this i have put below code in to web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>           
        <web-resource-name>my account</web-resource-name>
        <description>my account</description>
        <url-pattern>/my_account_*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

but it did not work. i also changed the URL patterns like below

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

then it worked but the problem is that this will open the every page in 
HTTPS, i don't want it to be open all the pages in HTTPS. i only need 
to open the pages which are starts with "my_account_"

im using glassfish

Answer (score 1):

*tldr;* According to specs, your `<url-pattern>` does not do what you expect it to do. See below for possible solutions.

---

In Servlet 3.0 spec, section 13.8.3 Processing requests (under the "Security" chapter), it describes how the security constraints for a request are selected:

> When a Servlet container receives a request, it shall use the algorithm described in
>   “Use of URL Paths” on page 95 to select the constraints (if any) defined on the urlpattern
>   that is the best match to the request URI.

The section pointed by the above describes how URLs are matched. Specifically in section 12.2 however, the mappings are specified:

> - A string **beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix** is used for
>     path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the
>     application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
>     and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

According to this your mapping of `/my_account_*` falls in the **LAST** category (it does not end with `/*` to fall in the first). This is why the mapping is not working.

### What can you do?

1. I would suggest changing you directory layout and instead of (e.g.)

   ```
   /my_account_file1.jsp
   /my_account_file2.jsp
   ```

   Make a directory and put those files inside:

   ```
   /my_account/
       file1.jsp
       file2.jsp
   ```

   And the mapping should become:

   ```
   <url-pattern>/my_account/*</url-pattern>
   ```
2. You can use a 3rd party security library, like Spring Security, Apache Shiro or JBoss Picketlink.
3. You can add a filter to `/*` and programmatically enforce security (**NO, DON'T DO IT YOURSELF, SEE POINT 2, INCLUDED HERE JUST FOR THE SAKE OF COMPLETENESS**). Similar approaches can be accomplished using servlets, but I recommend **AGAINST** this.